# C# Assign to an Array with many NumericUpdown Objects

Tags: c#, arrays, object, numericupdown

Ok so I am making a sudoku solver for fun (yes I know it's already been made many times over) so to let people input there values before solving I used numericalupdown (81 one of them to be exact)
and i wanted to assign all of them to an array:

```
        int[,] Sudoku = new int[9, 9];
```

and then on clicking "solve" the first thing it's supposed to do is put all the values in the array:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 81; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
            {
                if (x-1 == 0)
                {
                    Sudoku[x - 1, y - 1] = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown[y].Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    Sudoku[x - 1, y - 1] = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown[x][y].Value);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

obviously you can't do: "numbericupdown[y]" but thats for you to see what I am trying to do....

sooooo thoughts?

THANKS,
Craiggles

Comment: What's the type of `numericUpDown`? Is it an `int[][]`?

Answer (score 1):

If you put your `numericUpDown` controls into a 9x9 grid just like you have for the results, then copying the values will be straightforward.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            Sudoku[x, y] = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown[x, y].Value);
        }
    }

}
```

If the controls are actually all dropped onto the form, then don't do that, remove them from the form.  Use code to create them, place them programmatically, and put them into a 2d array.  Since this is a learning program anyways, that's good practice for doing GUI's programmatically instead of just by drag-n-drop.

Comment: Oh sweet, I really like this idea. How would I do that though? Can you link me to a place to teach me?

Comment: @Craiggles, when you use the designer to build stuff, it creates a `*.Designer.cs` file which is just C# code.  Read that code and you'll see how you can do the same thing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about constructing/placing them dynamically and at the same time putting them into an array or list, but if they are already laid out onto a form you can just add them to a generic list to iterate over them.

```
List<NumericUpDown> nums = new List<NumericUpDown>();
nums.add(numericUpDwown1);
```

then you could calculate nums[1]*nums[9]... or whatever

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are doing... Two suggestions:  1) put all of your controls into an array of NumericaUpDown objects.  Then you could do numericUpDown[y].Value.  Otherwise, 2) name the controls ending with numbers (or some similar convention) then use reflection to find the right one and get its value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no reason at all why you cannot create controls and store them in various collection classes - not just arrays.

I would consider putting these into some sort of structured set of collections that reflect the structure of a sudoku grid.

You could dynamically create and place the controls on the form as well as holding them in the collection.